# Naming a male pet Monkey

Tags: name

How would you name a male pet, Monkey?  Since 'scimmia' is female it doesn't seem right.  Scimmio, or is that slang for something else?

Comment: What I originally tried to enter, without the last sentence, got rejected as low quality, so I had to lengthen the post some

Comment: *Scimmia* is fine. For example in Italian we call Shere-Khan *tigre* although the character is manifestly male and the word is female. Grammatical gender does not have a one-to-one correspondence with biological sex. In my opinion this question is still low quality, though, since it is unmotivated.

Comment: This question should definitely be clarified, as the diversity of the answers shows. Is the OP asking about grammatical genders in Italian (if so, please clarify what you are asking)? a suggestion for a name for a pet (off-topic here)? whether “scimmio” is used in Italian (no)?

Comment: If @DaG got the question right, then it should be changed to "Is calling a male monkey pet _Scimmio_ correct, in Italian?" At least it would avoid users come out with fantasy names, which is out of the scope for this site, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe call it *scimmiotto*. The suffix *-otto* sounds cute in Italian, so it fits to a pet, regardless of age or size.

Answer (score 3):

"Scimmia" is for both genders.

In Italian there are many animals with female name for both genders, for instance: zebra, vipera, marmotta, balena, ...

Answer (score -1):

**Monketto**

- It's neither English or Italian.
- Has connotations of *monkey*, *small* and *cute*.
- The masculine suffix suits a male pet.
- Can be abbreviated to *ketto*.

Comment: Let me see. Answered the question? Yes. Low quality question? Yes. Down vote explained? No. First post encouragement? No. Typical Stack Overflow behaviour? Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: This does not answer the question. As far as I can tell this answer has very little to do with my the question indeed.

Comment: @Denis The question states *How would you name a male pet, Monkey?* In what way does this answer not address the question?

Comment: The question is low quality and very unclear (see my comment to the question), so it is unclear if the answer is relevant. And, in my not-so-humble opinion, “Monketto” is an awful name (among other reasons, because *monco* means “mutilated” in Italian), so I deem it “not useful”, which is exactly what “-1” means.

Comment: @DaG So, you penalize me because *you* have failed to review the question properly? The question has been up for 4 days, and despite being one of the most frequent posters here, *you've only just noticed*? It's a question that on any other Stack would have been on hold within hours because it is not possible for there to be a single correct answer; any answer that gives a name is as *useful* as any other. So you may say *not useful*. I say bullying.

Comment: @andy256: As I have written, I downvoted your answer for its specific merits (or lack thereof), not those of the question. In Italian “Monketto” sounds more or less like “Armlessy” could in English.

Comment: @andy256 Beyond "Monketto" being a horrible name, when a question is ambiguous and there are different possible interpretations, choosing to answer a blatantly off topic one is going to bring in some downvotes. I don't know why the question was not closed sooner, but this is a relatively low traffic site.

Comment: @Denis Being a low traffic site is all more reason for it to be well moderated. The two of you were quick enough to jump on my answer. Very selective logic.

Comment: I agree that Monketto pronunced as it's Italian  (that is, as written) sounds like "without arms", but if we pronunced it as it's English (that is "monkitto") is not so bad. I agree with you, sometime people are too much fussy, here. (Hence, +1).